# Vagrant up chef provision fails on normal up

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning, chef-solo

So I thought I had this all working, but it seems I'm still missing something.

When I `vagrant destroy --force && vagrant up`, everything works just fine. It creates the box and chef provisioning works as intended.

However, if I do a `vagrant halt` and then a `vagrant up`, I get the following error:

```
==> default: [2015-01-26T14:04:21+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook install not found. If you're loading install from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2015-01-26T14:04:21+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

`install` is a custom recipe, which just basically installs a bunch of packages, nothing too fancy.

Here is the `default.rb`, which is located in `site_cookbooks/install/recipies/`

```
# Install repos for PHP 5.5
remote_file "Creating PHP5.5 Repo" do
    path                    "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/webtatic_repo_latest.rpm"
    source                  "http://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm"
    action                  :create
end

rpm_package "Installing PHP5.5 Repo" do
    package_name            "jmxtrans"
    source                  "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/webtatic_repo_latest.rpm"
    action                  :install
end

# Install PHP 5.5 packages
yum_package "Installing PHP5.5" do
    package_name            "php55w"
    version                 "5.5.20-1.w6"
    allow_downgrade         true    
end

# Install PHP 5.5 Cli
yum_package "Installing PHP5.5-cli" do
    package_name            "php55w-cli"
    version                 "5.5.20-1.w6"
    allow_downgrade         true
end

# Install PHP 5.5 common
yum_package "Installing PHP5.5-common" do
    package_name            "php55w-common"
    version                 "5.5.20-1.w6"
    allow_downgrade         true
end

# Install PHP 5.5 mysql
yum_package "Installing PHP5.5-mysql" do
    package_name            "php55w-mysql"
    version                 "5.5.20-1.w6"
    allow_downgrade         true
end

# Install the mysql server
mysql_service "default" do
    instance                "property.ca"
    version                 "5.5"
    initial_root_password   node["install"]["mysql"]["password"]
    port                    "3306"
    bind_address            "0.0.0.0"
    action                  [:create, :start]
end

# Install the mysql client
mysql_client "default" do
    version                 "5.5"
    action                  :create
end

# Install Apache 2.4 repo
remote_file "Installing Apache 2.4 repo" do
    path                    "/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-httpd24.repo"
    source                  "http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/epel-httpd24.repo"
    action                  :create
end

# Install Apache 2.4 package
yum_package "Installing Apache 2.4" do
    package_name            "httpd24-apr"
    version                 "1.4.8-2.el6"
    allow_downgrade         true
end

# Install Git package
yum_package "Installing Git" do
    package_name            "git"
    version                 "1.7.1-3.el6_4.1"
    allow_downgrade         true
end


# Download composer
remote_file "Downloading composer" do
    path "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/composer_installer"
    source "https://getcomposer.org/installer"
    action :create
end

# Install composer
bash "Install composer" do
    user                    "root"
    cwd                     "/usr/bin"
    code <<-EOH
    php #{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/composer_installer -- ----install-/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    EOH
end
```

I have a `metadata.rb` which is located in `site_cookbooks/install` and looks like this:

```
name 'install'
maintainer 'SynackSA'
maintainer_email 'synacksa@email.ca'
license 'MIT'
description 'Install the dev environment'
version '1.0.0'

depends 'mysql'
```

My `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "chef/centos-6.5"

    # Plugins
    config.berkshelf.enabled = true
    config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest    

    config.vm.hostname = "site.ca"    
    config.vm.network "public_network"

    config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/PropertyDev/Projects/property.ca", "/var/www/site.ca"
    config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/MyUser/Projects/scripts", "/var/www/scripts"


    # run: "always"
    config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|

        chef.json = {
            "install" => {
                "mysql" => {
                    "password" => "password"
                }
            }
        }

        chef.cookbooks_path = "site_cookbooks"
        chef.add_recipe "install"
        # chef.log_level = :debug
    end

end
```

My `Berksfile`:

```
# encoding: utf-8
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

cookbook "mysql", "~> 6.0.10"
cookbook "install", path: "site_cookbooks/install"
```

Full debug output from `vagrant reload --provision` with `debug_level = :debug`

```
» vagrant reload --provision
==> default: Loading Berkshelf datafile...
==> default: Sharing cookbooks with VM
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Checking if box 'chef/centos-6.5' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Updating Vagrant's Berkshelf...
==> default: Resolving cookbook dependencies...
==> default: Fetching 'install' from source at site_cookbooks/install
==> default: Using install (1.0.0) from source at site_cookbooks/install
==> default: Using rbac (1.0.2)
==> default: Using smf (2.2.1)
==> default: Using yum-mysql-community (0.1.12)
==> default: Using resource-control (0.1.1)
==> default: Using yum (3.5.2)
==> default: Using mysql (6.0.10)
==> default: Vendoring install (1.0.0) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/install
==> default: Vendoring mysql (6.0.10) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/mysql
==> default: Vendoring rbac (1.0.2) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/rbac
==> default: Vendoring resource-control (0.1.1) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/resource-control
==> default: Vendoring smf (2.2.1) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/smf
==> default: Vendoring yum (3.5.2) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/yum
==> default: Vendoring yum-mysql-community (0.1.12) to /Users/User/.berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/shelves/berkshelf20150127-46811-19w58cq-default/yum-mysql-community
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Available bridged network interfaces:
1) en4: Display Ethernet
2) en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)
3) en1: Thunderbolt 1
4) en2: Thunderbolt 2
5) p2p0
6) awdl0
7) bridge0
==> default: When choosing an interface, it is usually the one that is
==> default: being used to connect to the internet.
    default: Which interface should the network bridge to? 1
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: bridged
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Checking for host entries
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/User/Projects/vagrant_test
    default: /var/www/scripts => /Users/User/Projects/scripts
    default: /var/www/site.ca => /Users/User/Projects/site.ca
==> default: Chef 12.0.3 Omnibus package is already installed.
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
==> default: Detected Chef (latest) is already installed
Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:31+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:31+00:00] DEBUG: Fork successful. Waiting for new chef pid: 2977
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:31+00:00] DEBUG: Forked instance now converging
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:31+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.0.3 ***
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:31+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2977
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:31+00:00] DEBUG: Chef-client request_id: 03997806-45c2-4d61-a9ab-029c3960788e
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] DEBUG: Building node object for property.ca
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] DEBUG: Extracting run list from JSON attributes provided on command line
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[install]"] from CLI options
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] DEBUG: Applying attributes from json file
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] DEBUG: Platform is centos version 6.5
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] INFO: Run List is [recipe[install]]
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] INFO: Run List expands to [install]
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for property.ca
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] INFO: Running start handlers
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] INFO: Start handlers complete.
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] DEBUG: Re-raising exception: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound - Cookbook install not found. If you're loading install from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook/cookbook_collection.rb:38:in `block in initialize'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.0.1/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `yield'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.0.1/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.0.1/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:277:in `[]'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:277:in `each_cookbook_dep'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:255:in `add_cookbook_with_deps'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:88:in `block in cookbook_order'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:86:in `each'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:86:in `cookbook_order'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:98:in `compile_libraries'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:71:in `compile'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:92:in `load'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:73:in `setup_run_context'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:235:in `setup_run_context'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:397:in `run'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:261:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:215:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:201:in `run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:245:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:234:in `loop'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:234:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:224:in `run_application'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
==> default:   /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default:   /usr/bin/chef-solo:40:in `load'
==> default:   /usr/bin/chef-solo:40:in `<main>'
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] DEBUG: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook install not found. If you're loading install from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/cookbook/cookbook_collection.rb:38:in `block in initialize'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.0.1/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `yield'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.0.1/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/ohai-8.0.1/lib/ohai/mash.rb:77:in `default'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:277:in `[]'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:277:in `each_cookbook_dep'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:255:in `add_cookbook_with_deps'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:88:in `block in cookbook_order'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:86:in `each'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:86:in `cookbook_order'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:98:in `compile_libraries'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context/cookbook_compiler.rb:71:in `compile'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/run_context.rb:92:in `load'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/policy_builder/expand_node_object.rb:73:in `setup_run_context'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:235:in `setup_run_context'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/client.rb:397:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:261:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:249:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:215:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:38:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:201:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:245:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:234:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:234:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:224:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/apps/chef/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:40:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:40:in `<main>'
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook install not found. If you're loading install from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
==> default: [2015-01-27T21:00:34+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT - ANSWER**

After some more investigation, with the help of @coderanger, it seems with versions 1.7.X there is a problem where sometimes the chef share directory isn't created on subsequent `vagrant up --provision` commands. I downgraded to 1.6.5, which seems to have fixed the problem. You can see the problem in the changelog (https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Check that after the first time, the shared folders are being setup correctly. You can test with `vagrant reload --provision`.

Comment: @coderanger `vagrant reload --provision` produced the same errors. The only way it seems is to do a destroy first.

Comment: Please include the full output from a failed provision with log_level at debug.

Comment: @coderanger vagrant log_level or chef log_level?

Comment: Chef log level, though I guess vagrant debug wouldn't hurt either but I'm less familiar reading that.

Comment: @coderanger Okay, I've updated all relevant sections, since I started use Berksfile and also included the debug out for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69695/discussion-between-synacksa-and-coderanger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy of either Vagrant or the Berkshelf plugin are likely out of date. I don't see the berks-created temp folder being setup as a shared folder. Check your version of `vagrant-berkshelf`.

Comment: It is created when I do a `vagrant up` after a `vagrant destroy`. Should it be doing it on every `vagrant up` command?

Comment: It should there on any vagrant call that results in running Chef.

Comment: Chef DK on my host = 0.3.6, Chef-solo on vagrant = 12.0.3, Vagrant on host = 1.7.2, Berks on host 3.2.3, Ruby on host = ruby 2.0.0. vagrant-berkshelf  (4.0.2), vagrant-omnibus (1.4.1), vagrant-share (1.1.3, system). From what I can tell, everything is latest versions.

Comment: After some more investigation, it seems with versions 1.7.X there is a problem where sometimes the chef share directory isn't created on subsequent `vagrant up --provision` commands. I downgraded to 1.6.5, which seems to have fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the general direction